# Will creation of java.time.LocalTime also trigger creation of sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo

Tags: java, heap-memory, java-time, localtime

Recently there is a process we’re working on taking a lot more memory than expected. Upon checking the heap there are a lot of `java.util.LocalTime` created. Which can be explained because we do store some data in a timemap with `LocalTime` as key. Probably there is too much of that data generated from upstream compared to the expected.

However, there is a surprise that also a lot of `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo` are created. We don't use this class; will it generated by `LocalTime`? But if we check the source code of `java.time.LocalTime`, I don't see `ZoneInfo` is used; does anyone have an idea about that?

Comment: It wouldn’t make sense. `ZoneInfo` is used by `java.util.Calendar` and its subclass `GregorianCalendar`. I don’t know whether it’s used by some `java.time` class too, my guess would be not. If you’re still suspecting `LocalTime`, you may try generating a lot of `LocalTime` objects in a test program and see if any `ZoneInfo` objects appear on your heap.

Comment: Do you call `LocalTime.now(...)`?

Comment: Yes, I did call LocalTime.now(), I did see it using ZoneOffset but if I look into ZoneOffset it doesn't use ZoneInfo as far as I can tell

Comment: `LocalTime.now()` will at least trigger loading of `ZoneId`-class and timezone data. This might also trigger loading of `ZoneInfo` which is based on the same tz-data in the background (not tested).

Comment: Thanks, how that trigger happening? I just wonder

Comment: @OleV.V. It makes some sense because Oracle wants a) to preserve the backwards compatibility (keeping the old timezone-related classes) and b) wants to minimize the maintenance effort by keeping all old and new zone classes together in the background (as far as the system tz is involved).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer but now I have found some time to **inspect the JDK-sources**.

If you call `LocalTime.now()` then `java.time` will use the system timezone (an implicit dependency).

```
public static LocalTime now() {
    return now(Clock.systemDefaultZone());
}
```

And then `Clock` loads `ZoneId.systemDefault()`:

```
public static Clock systemDefaultZone() {
    return new SystemClock(ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

Finally, the class `java.util.TimeZone` is used to find the default zone.

```
public static ZoneId systemDefault() {
    return TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId();
}
```

And if you look into the source of `TimeZone.getDefault()` then you will see at some depth down the stack:

```
private static TimeZone getTimeZone(String ID, boolean fallback) {
    TimeZone tz = ZoneInfo.getTimeZone(ID);
    if (tz == null) {
        tz = parseCustomTimeZone(ID);
        if (tz == null && fallback) {
            tz = new ZoneInfo(GMT_ID, 0);
        }
    }
    return tz;
}
```

Voilá, the class `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo` will be loaded, too.

Comment: Yes in fact I've take a look of the source, but it look like it should get a cached copy of TimeZone instead of look up everytime. Maybe a bug in JDK?

Anyway, think it better to prevent using LocalTime.now() but LocalTime.now(Clock)